# Section height is 0 because of div's absolute position inside

Tags: html, css, position, height, absolute

So basically I've got a section tag, with 3 divs inside, positioned absolute (used for isotope plugin)

```
              <section id="section1" class="cd-section"> // pos. static/relative has height 0px
                    <div class="itemIso"> // pos. absolute, height ~900px
                          div1
                    </div>
                    <div class="itemIso"> // pos. absolute, height ~700px
                          div2
                    </div>
                    <div class="itemIso"> // pos. absolute, height ~600px
                          div3
                    </div>
              </section>
```

Here's a pic:
[image]

Now obviously my problem is that since divs have position absolute and section1 is static/relative, it's height is 0, and I want it to be 900+700+600=whatever,2200px? is it?
I've got 6 of these sections, I can't set a fixed height, since it might be changing.

Any jQuery,js,whatever stuff that can solve this?

Comment: so maybe position absolute is not your friend here, you can maybe use display:inline-block; divs, also in your example, what height do you want your container to have ? 600 ? 1100 ? 500 ? explain how your absolute elements are placed so we can help ;)

Comment: I wasn't the one who made them absolute, it's an isotope grid (https://isotope.metafizzy.co/) im using, it's somehow a portfolio im trying to make with it.

Comment: and you have the js loaded on your page and initialized with $grid.isotope ? Because it not something you can reproduce easily without js , isotope automaticaly set the good height for your div

Comment: Can the position be overridden with CSS?

Comment: it can, but it will ruin the whole point of using Isotope Grid.

Comment: @themarksmaker If the isotope library is vital to this question, then you should add the tag for it. And throw the [height] tag away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best solution is recalculate the section's height after each change of the children' height. With this approach you need to call `calculateHeight()` function after load images, fonts or resize screen. Also you need to be sure that external plugin don't overlay the elements, like the 2nd and 3rd section of the example.

```js
function calculateHeight(){
  var maxHeight = 0;

  $(".section > div").each(function() {
    var height = $(this).height();   
    height += $(this).position().top;    
    
    if (height > maxHeight)
        maxHeight = height;
  });

  $('.section').height(maxHeight);
}


$(function() {
  
  calculateHeight();
  
  $(window).resize(calculateHeight);
});
```

```css
.section{
  position: relative; 
  background: red;
}

.section-i{
  position :absolute;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  
}

.section-i.s1{
  top: 15px;
  height: 100px;
}

.section-i.s2{
  top: 130px;
  height: 200px;
}

.section-i.s3{
  top: 300px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="section">
  <div class="section-i s1">
  </div>
  <div class="section-i s2">
  </div>
  <div class="section-i s3">
  </div>
</section>
```

Hope I help you

Comment: pretty sure that in your example section class section has 0 height

Comment: Sorry, chage $('#section').height(maxHeight) for this $('.section').height(maxHeight), my misstake. I know the solution is wire but check the for the height and the top for the latest placed element.

Comment: problem is that on first load it doesn't work well, it's missing like ~100-150px?(section gets like 2100px height), after I resize window it snaps right on point (2209px height). have any idea why?

Comment: Well, I think can be the elements inside the items, for example, an image or font are loading async, then when this resources are loaded they changes the size of its containers, in fact this could be happening to the 3rd plugin.  Could you check that?

Comment: Could u create a fidle?

Comment: It's way too complicated, using it on wordpress and I got a lot of content going on there. Is there anywhere I can put a link directly? can I put it here?

Comment: http://fiber-feel.com/softelligence/industry/ , the idea is that I want to make 6 sections synced with that menu on the left ( that gets active - blue circle ). Anyways you can get me on skype at scrilsandrei if you'd like to help more? lol

Answer (score 2):

using JQuery...

Note that this example doesn't factor in the positioning of the child divs, only their height.

```js
$(function() {
  var sectionHeight = 0;

  $("#section1 > div").each(function() {
    sectionHeight += $(this).height();
  });

  $('#section1').height(sectionHeight);
});
```

```css
.cd-section {
  position: relative;
  background: lightgrey;
  border: 5px solid red;
}

.cd-section>div {
  position: absolute;
  height: 200px;
  width: 100%;
  background: grey;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section id="section1" class="cd-section">
  <div class="itemIso">
  </div>
  <div class="itemIso">
  </div>
  <div class="itemIso">
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Yea, exactly what I was looking for. Minor changes and it works like a charm. Cheers mate!

Comment: This approach doesn't care about position of the element, this assume that each element is one after other without spacing like margin or top. You need to check that.